# I have many names, but one. I have infinite names, but none. All, but none, are mine. What am I?

Tags: riddle

I have many names, but one.

I have infinite names, but none.

All, but none, are mine.

Hint:

> Think about it from a figurative POV.

Comment: Is this related to computer languages in any way?

Answer (score 12):

It's a bit of a weak solution and maybe silly, but it's the only thing that came to my mind at the moment.

I think you are..

> something.

---

*I have many names, but one.*

> If **something** refers to the presence of a *thing*, then **something** can be anything except for **nothing**, since by our earlier assumption **nothing** would refer to the absence of a *thing*.
>  So **something** can be anything except **nothing**.

*I have infinite names, but none.*

> Since *anything* is a list of infinite possibilities of *things*, and **something** can be anything, there's an infinite list of possibilities of what **something** can be. However since it must be *something*, it cannot be **nothing**.
>  So **something** can have any name, except for **nothing**, the only thing it cannot be.

*All, but none, are mine.*

> Just repeating the earlier "conclusions". **Something** can be *anything* except **nothing**.

Comment: I hope this is it. Good job making none and one the same.

Answer (score 8):

Are you:

> Arya Stark?

Many names, but one -

> A girl has no name

Infinite names, but none -

> the many faced God has many faces

All but none, are mine -

> She is not the person she imitates

Comment: Since the hint was think figuratively not literally I doubt this is the answer, but damn does it fit!

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> All numbers except Zero

I have many names, but one.

> You have the names of all the numbers except Zero, which is one name

I have infinite names, but none.

> There are infinite numbers, hence infinite names and None stands for Zero, which isn't included.

All, but none, are mine.

> All numbers except Zero, which is none, belong